# Can you make Sublime linter work with Laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, sublimetext, laravel-blade, error-detection

I use http://www.sublimelinter.com in all my projects is there a linter that works in blade.php pages?

Or how can I make it to work with blade.php pages?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install **Laravel Blade Highlighter** package 
https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade

And add to SublimeLinter settings:

```
    "syntax_map": {
        "blade": "html"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I use this package in Sublime Text 3, and it works like a charm: https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade

But I'm not sure if it will work on Sublime linter. Guess you have to try it out.

Comment: Yes im using also this package but i think you can not use it as a linter. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: No problem. Good luck!